# Cannot send post message to webview during background state in android using react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am able to detect when my app is going to background state however I am unable to send a postmessage on the webview when the app is going or currently in background state

Below is a sample code from my app

```
react-native

const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', nextAppState => {
   if (appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
    console.log('AppState : Foreground');
   } 
   else if(appState.current.match(/active/) && nextAppState === 'background') {
    console.log('AppState : Background');
    johnnywebs.current.postMessage('closing');
   }

   console.log(appState,nextAppState);

   appState.current = nextAppState;
        setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
   });
```

```
my website javascript code

document.addEventListener("message", message => {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('test','data');
    //data is sent to a php file so i will know if the postmessage was called
    navigator.sendBeacon("beacon.php", sampledata);
});

window.addEventListener("message", message => {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('test','data');
    //data is sent to a php file so i will know if the postmessage was called
    navigator.sendBeacon("beacon.php", sampledata);
});
```

When I'm in console the code will work as expected and I am able to receive data from the beacon but when I compile it to app the beacon is not received.